# Multiplication of rings is an abelian group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring without identity.

Suppose that the multiplication $ \cdot :  R \times R \rightarrow R $ is an abelian group homomorphism.

For $a, b \in R$ what can we conclude about the product of $a \cdot b$ ?

Comment: If you call the multiplication abelian **group** homomorphism it then must be that under that multiplication $\;R\;$ is a group , so how come it has no (multiplicative) unit, what you probably call "identity"?

Comment: @DonAntonio $R$ is an abelian group under addition!

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't think that's right, I think that here multiplication is a homomorphism between the two groups $(R\times R,+)$ and $(R,+)$.

Comment: I know that, @Zhen ! But if the problem states that the product is a *group* homom. I think it follows that is under **that** multiplication...or else let the OP address and clear out this, of course.

Comment: Perhaps so, @TomOldfield...yet I think there's room for quite some confussion here

Comment: If you see the upvoted and accepted answer, there doesn't seem to be any use of the fact that $\,R\,$ has no "identity"...Odd, ain't it? Nevertheless, it seems to be the OP is happy with this.

Comment: @DonAntonio The answer shows that if $R$ has a multiplicative identity (unequal to $0$), the multiplication $m\colon R\times R\to R$ cannot induce a group homomorphism $(R\times R,+)\to (R,+)$.

Comment: @DonAntonio I am sorry if the question is confusing, I simply typed it out as it is given to me. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $m\colon R\times R\to R$ be the multiplication of $R$ and suppose $m$ is an abelian group homomorphism on the addition groups of $R\times R$ and $R$. Then, for any $a,b\in R$:
$$ab = m(a,b) = m((a,0)+(0,b)) = m(a,0)+m(0,b) = 0+0 = 0.$$